# Regex replace with increment

Tags: java, regex

I use `myString.replaceAll("(Chapter.*?)br","Chapter **INCREMENT**");`

I want to paste an `**increment**` instead of `INCREMENT`, but I don't have an idea how I can do it.

I have next text:

> Chapter A br
>
> TextTextTextA
>
> Chapter B345 br
>
> TextTextTextB345
>
> Chapter AB br
>
> TextTextTextAB

It has to look like:

> Chapter 1 br
>
> TextTextTextA
>
> Chapter 2 br
>
> TextTextTextB345
>
> Chapter 3 br
>
> TextTextTextAB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have chapters with different index. As example, Chapter A and Chapter B. I'm grabbing all chapters by regex and change unique chapter to Chapter + Increment.

**Found solution:**

```
int n = 0;
Pattern r = Pattern.compile("(Chapter.*?)<br />");

Matcher m = r.matcher(fileToShow);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(0));
    fileToShow = fileToShow.replaceAll(m.group(0),"<Chapter "+ ++n +">");
}
```